# Update a row if ID exists else Insert

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code of a .php file. The column "memberid" has a unique index. When a user enters a record with an existing memberid, the record must get updated else a new row is created.

I also want to show an alert box. For test purposes I added like the way below, but it is not firing. No message is displayed.

I also want to know whether it is the right approach to handle insert/update automatically?

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=socialprofile.html">
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once("../Lib/dbaccess.php");

    //Retrieve values from Input Form
    $CandidateID = $_POST["inCandidate"];
    $SocialProfile = $_POST["inActivities"];

    $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO candidate_db_social (memberid, socialactivities, lastupdated) VALUES (".$CandidateID.",'".$SocialProfile."',now())";
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE candidate_db_social SET socialactivities='".$SocialProfile."', lastupdated=now() WHERE memberid=".$CandidateID;
    try
    {
        $Result = dbaccess::InsertRecord($InsertQuery); 
    }
    catch(exception $ex)
    {
        $Result = dbaccess::InsertRecord($UpdateQuery);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$ex."');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact, that your code is wide open to any kind of sql injections? I don't know what *exactly* your "dbaccess" does, but the way you concatenate raw request data into the query gives me goosebumps. Maybe you should consider using prepared statements or at the very least `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will change accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [MySQL `REPLACE` keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html). It works exactly like `INSERT`, but overwrites existing records based on primary key. Read up on the details though, because it's not exactly equivalent to trying an INSERT, followed by an UPDATE.

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) might be what you need instead. Situations with triggers or foreign keys come to mind. Longer syntax however :)

Comment: is ON DUPLICATE supports for all version?

Comment: I should note, that `replace` and `insert ... on duplicate key update` do completely different things and, I must assure you, that the main difference lies *not* in the syntax.

Comment: @shylent: I never claimed the difference lies in the syntax. If it was purely syntax, I wouldn't have even mentioned the second option :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY clause:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Also see REPLACE:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE INTO candidate_db_social (memberid, socialactivities, lastupdated) VALUES (".$CandidateID.",'".$SocialProfile."',now())";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax, as in:

```
insert into t values ('a', 'b', 'c') on duplicate key
  update a='a', b='b', c='c'
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES() 
                       ON duplicate KEY UPDATE ..;
```

example :

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/29/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-summary-counters/

Answer (score 0):

I usually just check for the existence of a record ID value from either the $_POST or $_GET array (depending on the situation). If a value exists and is numeric, attempt to UPDATE the row with the corresponding ID; if not perform an INSERT query.